# Scope issue within Backbone model.fetch() callback (calling setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've a master view (*Services*) with a collection of child views (*Service*). Each child view needs to refresh itself every 5 seconds. To do this I had the following [extract]:

```
Service: Backbone.View.extend({
    ...

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        _.bindAll(this, 'update');
    },

    render: function () {
        ...
        this.update();
        return this;
    },

    update: function() {
        this.model.fetch();
        setTimeout(this.update, 5000);
    }

    ...
```

The `setTimeout` call to `update()`  of course worked as `this` was correctly bound to the view in question.

The problem comes  in when I move setTimeout into the callback for `fetch`, as `this` now points to the global scope:

```
    update: function() {
        this.model.fetch({ success: function() {
            // this is now global
            setTimeout(this.update, 5000);
        }});            
    }
```

How can I achieve a continous (non-overlapping) update function. Or - how can I apply the view's scope to `this` inside the `fetch` callback?

### Update

Was just going over this old question, and for future reference I follow this pattern nowadays as I find `_.bind` OTT here:

```
    update: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.model.fetch({ success: function() {
            setTimeout(self.update, 5000);
        }});            
    }
```

Comment: definitely a better solution :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the options is to use Underscore `_.bind` function:

```
update: function() {
    this.model.fetch({ success: _.bind(function() {
        setTimeout(this.update, 5000);
    }, this)});            
}
```

Comment: Using Backbone 0.9.1 this gives me an "Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old question, but the success and failure events return three values: model, response and options. Instead of calling `this.update` within the success function, you can call `model.update`:

```
update: function() {
    this.model.fetch({ success: function( model, response, options) {
       setTimeout(model.update, 5000);
    }});            
}
```